# How to make a user loged in (authenticated) in django with Reactjs? i'm using Django rest api to connect django and react

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

Here is the view i created in Django Views to verify the if the user is authenticated or not,
but even if the user is valide, whene i try to get the currect user i get Null

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        data = request.data
        usr = authenticate(username=data["username"], password=data["password"])

        if usr in not None:
            login(request,usr)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: How did you save the user? And what did you set as `USERNAME_FIELD`?

Comment: i userd jwt but the problem is with the access token and refresh token, i have no idea how to use them

Comment: If you have the token, just use it in your request headers for the other views

Comment: @bdbd so in all the request that i have to send i have to include de token in it?

Comment: If you are using mainly JWT, then yes

Comment: @bdbd thank you man for your time

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the authentication methods provided in [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

TokenAuthentication is the easiest one to implement, but I recommend you to read the whole section first so you understand the advantages and disadvantages of each method.